# ImageMagick - how to preserve exact palette in .PNG

Tags: images, conversion, imagemagick

I'm trying to use `convert(1)` from ImageMagick to convert from `.tga` to `.png` (and back again later), while **preserving exact palette** that was used.

Source image is TARGA color indexed file, having a standard 8-bit 256-color palette to 24-bit RGB values.
Of those 256 colors, 239 are actually used in image for the pixel values.

However, using simple `convert a.tga a.png`, PNG is created which drops unused palette colors, and other palette values get their indexes changed too. Converting to `.tiff` or `.gif` works just fine and palette is preserved by default (I've verified colormap manually with `identify -verbose a.tiff`)

```
% identify a.png a.tga a.tif a.gif
a.png PNG 320x200 320x200+0+0 8-bit sRGB 239c 29549B 0.000u 0:00.000
a.tga TGA 320x200 320x200+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 64790B 0.000u 0:00.000
a.tif TIFF 320x200 320x200+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 65818B 0.000u 0:00.000
a.gif GIF 320x200 320x200+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 29830B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

What I would like is for palette to remain exactly the same (for example, if in `TGA` `index 55` had values `R=200 G=150 B=100`, the resulting `PNG` should have *same* values  `R=200 G=150 B=100` at *same* index position `55`. Also index values not used in that image should also be preserved at same index position with same value (reason being they're going to be used later by 3rd party code which has hardcoded index values for pixel used in overlays)

In essence, I'd like **complete color palette to remain exactly the same** while converting `TGA`->`PNG`->`TGA`.

Can imagemagick do that and how (or if not, is there an alternative to coding my own tools)?
(I tried playing with few other options, like `-colors 256`, `-remap a.tga`, `png8:` etc. but to no avail)

I'm using Debian Buster with `ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16` if it matters.

**Update:** It seems there exist an option [-define png:preserve-colormap=true](https://ulfirefightersafety.org/ImageMagick-7.0.10-28/www/defines.html) which sound just like the thing I want, but it does not seem to work when using palette ?!

```
% convert a.tga -define png:preserve-colormap=true png8:a.png
convert-im6.q16: Valid palette required for paletted images `a.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1641.
```

(it works without `png8:`, but then it creates Truecolor PNG (`color_type:2`; without palette) instead of Indexed (`color_type: 3`; with palette), which defeats the purpose...

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29587679/2600099) is informatively related, and also gives surprisingly simple perl script workaround PNG writer to manually work around the problem if I'd run out of options.

However, I've tried `GraphicsMagick 1.3.35` package as alternative, and while it doesn't seem to work with my TGA files (although it claims it does), it does provide part of the solution.

In the end, it was combining ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick that did the trick, producing color-indexed `PNG` with same palette as in `TGA` with this pipeline:

```
convert a.tga tiff:- | gm convert - a.png
```

It is kludgy, but it works. I'd still love to see cleaner solution if anyone has it...